# Hang inside mount shutters on drywall , or add window casing

Tags: walls, wood, windows, shutters

I am looking to install inside mount shutters. I have drywall around the windows, no decorative molding/casing inside. Here is a pic of how it is right now.

[image: picture of window opening with dimensions]

When I order shutters from Bali I see that when you have no molding or sill it automatically sends you to get outside mount shutters, which I don't want (want inside mount only). This is the option I am talking about on Bali website.

[image]

I have two options now.

**Option-1:**
Attach the inside mount frames to the drywall (behind we have studs/framing), but it looks like I should not install inside mount on top of drywall. It needs some wood casing or simple wood frame after the drywall to make sure the shutters are firmly attached to the walls. Is that correct? or I am OK to install the shutters to the drywall directly?

**Option-2:**
Add 1x3 around my windows as window casing. Something like the image below.

[image]

I am a little confused. Need help in deciding which one of these is the least time consuming option.

Updated 9/21 after reading comments:
The drywall thickness is standard thickness around the windows, 3/4" I think, and I am sure there are studs behind on the sides, and there will be 2x4 at top and bottom too. I don't understand why on Bali website when you specify drywall (or say you have no wood molding around) it automatically takes you to outside mount shutters. I initially assumed it was because the drywall on top of studs may not be able to take lateral pressure of the shutters and the screw could get dislodged or get bend inside the drywall part. The screws they send are really long, like 3-4" from what I remember so I will secure it to studs/framing for sure. You don't think the 3/4" drywall in front of studs will be a problem here, especially for the sides where shutters hang, right? Like in the img below, the screw won't move down because of the weight of shutters since drywall is softer?

[image]

Comment: I embedded the image to make it easier for everyone to see. Also, removed the "best option" question, as that's an opinion and opinion-based questions are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Even if there's wood trim around the window, there will be drywall behind the trim. I'm not sure what Bali's reasons for insisting it be done this way are. The only way to find out would be to call them. The only possible reason I can think of is that they may presume that without any trim, there may not be enough depth to mount the shutters inside the opening. If you've got the depth _and_ that's the reason, I'd say go for it.

Answer (score 4):

The shutters can be installed directly to the drywall *if you use screws long enough to go through the drywall, which is typically 1/2" or 5/8" thick, and into the wood framing behind the drywall*.

Comment: This. Exactly. OP won't mount them to the drywall, but to the studs behind the drywall. There just happens to be drywall in between.

Comment: Drywall in areas like that is typically at least 1/8" thicker and as much as 1/4" or more due to corner beads, etc. Of course that's only relevant if screws are minimally long to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the comments/suggestions everyone!

Comment: @kyle  I am not sure if this was the correct way of doing it but I edited my question to add some more details.

Comment: The attachment of  the shutter through the drywall is not an issue with long enough screws whether it is an outside mount as "Bali" suggests or inside mount as you prefer. Is there perhaps another reason "Bali" wants you to mount outside ? This is something you need to check with them directly about before you order.